# sympy diff gives me unexpected results

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I expect this to return -0.5, but instead it returns 0.

```
from sympy import *

sigma = Symbol('sigma')
y = log(sigma)
f = lambdify(sigma, diff(exp(-2 * y), y))
f(2)
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

Try differentiating not in `y`, but in `sigma`.

```
f = lambdify(sigma, diff(exp(-2 * y), sigma))
```

hope this helps

Comment: This gives me −0.25. I would like to differentiate with respect to y and get back -0.5.